# How to repeatedly store data in linked lists?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a program where I want to continue adding in an integer and string in a linked list. However when I print out the linked list it only prints out the last entered values and not the previous ones. So If I entered 3 Sally and then entered 6 Bob the linked list only prints out 6 bob. I want to be able to print out everything in the linkedlist no just the last entered.

```
public class Texteditor  {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static int myInt;
static String myString;

public Texteditor(int a, String s){
    myInt = a;
    myString = s;
}
public String toString(){
    return myInt + " " + myString;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
     LinkedList<Texteditor> myLL = new LinkedList<Texteditor>();

    int isExit = 0;
    System.out.println("Hello Welcome to Your Personal Texteditor! ");
    System.out.println("There are many options you can do with this text editor");
    System.out.println("1. If you enter a line number with no text, the line number will be deleted.");
    System.out.println("2. If you enter LIST alone the editor will print everything in the list with line number.");
    System.out.println("3. If you enter RESEQUENCE the line numbers will be resequenced to start at 10.");
    while(isExit ==0) {
 //   myLL = new LinkedList<Texteditor>();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please enter the line number: ");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    myInt = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Plese enter text as a string: ");
    Scanner kb1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    myString = kb1.nextLine();
    Texteditor a1 = new Texteditor(myInt, myString); 
    myLL.add(a1); 
    System.out.println("Would you like to keep going? Enter yes or no: " );
    Scanner kb2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (kb2.next().equals("no")){
        isExit = 1;
    }
    } 

    for (Texteditor element : myLL){
        System.out.println(element + "\n");
    }        
}    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myInt` and `myString` are static, which means they're shared by instances. Make them non-static and the code should work correctly.

Also, don't recreate the `Scanner` every time in the loop. Once is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making the myInt and myString variables static.  Remove the static modifier and then in your while loop, instead of referencing the class's myInt and myString variables, create local int and String variables instead.

```
public class Texteditor  {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 int myInt;
 String myString;

    public Texteditor(int a, String s){
        myInt = a;
        myString = s;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return myInt + " " + myString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Texteditor> myLL = new LinkedList<Texteditor>();

        int isExit = 0;
        System.out.println("Hello Welcome to Your Personal Texteditor! ");
        System.out.println("There are many options you can do with this text editor");
        System.out.println("1. If you enter a line number with no text, the line number will be deleted.");
        System.out.println("2. If you enter LIST alone the editor will print everything in the list with line number.");
        System.out.println("3. If you enter RESEQUENCE the line numbers will be resequenced to start at 10.");
        while(isExit ==0) {
     //   myLL = new LinkedList<Texteditor>();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Please enter the line number: ");
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            int myInt = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Plese enter text as a string: ");
            Scanner kb1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String myString = kb1.nextLine();
            Texteditor a1 = new Texteditor(myInt, myString); 
            myLL.add(a1); 
            System.out.println("Would you like to keep going? Enter yes or no: " );
            Scanner kb2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (kb2.next().equals("no")){
                isExit = 1;
            }
        } 

        for (Texteditor element : myLL){
            System.out.println(element + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the variables myInt and myString are static and hence they don't belong to each individual object (they belong to the class). Thus when you reference them here:

```
for (Texteditor2 element : myLL){
                System.out.println(element + "\n");
     }
```

You're calling the same values you set last n amount of times.

This should fix the problem:

Create a new TextEditorObject file:

```
public class TextEditorObject {
     int myInt;
     String myString;

    public TextEditorObject(int a, String s){
        myInt = a;
        myString = s;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return myInt + " " + myString;
    }
}
```

Change Texteditor like so:

```
public class Texteditor  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myInt;
    String myString;

    LinkedList<TextEditorObject> myLL = new LinkedList<TextEditorObject>();

    int isExit = 0;
    System.out.println("Hello Welcome to Your Personal Texteditor! ");
    System.out.println("There are many options you can do with this text editor");
    System.out.println("1. If you enter a line number with no text, the line number will be deleted.");
    System.out.println("2. If you enter LIST alone the editor will print everything in the list with line number.");
    System.out.println("3. If you enter RESEQUENCE the line numbers will be resequenced to start at 10.");
    while(isExit ==0) {
 //   myLL = new LinkedList<Texteditor>();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please enter the line number: ");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    myInt = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Plese enter text as a string: ");
    Scanner kb1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    myString = kb1.nextLine();
    TextEditorObject a1 = new TextEditorObject(myInt, myString); 
    myLL.add(a1); 
    System.out.println("Would you like to keep going? Enter yes or no: " );
    Scanner kb2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (kb2.next().equals("no")){
        isExit = 1;
    }
    } 

    for (TextEditorObject element : myLL){
        System.out.println(element + "\n");
    }

}
}
```